# Ruby exclude value in range

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I want to build an array using range (0..x) while excluding certain ranges and values.

Example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, .., 50, 60, .., 98, 100]
```

How is this done?

Comment: What are the certain values you want to exclude?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is:

```
array = [1, 2, 3,..., 50, 60,..., 98, 100]
```

If this means `array` is to contain the numbers `1` through `50`, `60` through `98` and `100`, then you can write that:

```
array = [*1..50, *60..98, 100]
  #=> [1, 2, 3,...49, 50, 60, 61, 62,...98, 100]
```

Comment: 98 to 100 was meant to highlight the exclusion of 99. Is the only way to exclude using this method, to stop an array and begin a new one?

Comment: You could write `[*1..50, *([*60..100]-[99])]`. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting one range from another:

```
(1..100).to_a - (51...60).to_a
```

To remove additional specific values, create an array of those values and subtract them too:

```
(1..100).to_a - (51...60).to_a - [82, 56, 23]
```

To add some cleanliness:

```
values_to_remove = [(51..60), [34,67,98]].flat_map(&:to_a)
(1..100).to_a - values_to_remove
```

Comment: How about specific values ie non ranges? @Brennan

Comment: Is there a way to remove the redundancy of .to_a? @Brennan

Comment: edited again. Unfortunately, when dealing with ranges, there must be at least a little `to_a` action going on.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails 6, you can build the example array in question using ranges + [excluding](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/excluding):

```
(1..100).excluding(*(51..59), 100)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a reference to this Range#excluding method? I don't see it in the latest docs.

Comment: @eeeeeean Edited with clarification of this method being available in Rails since version 6

Answer (score 0):

> I want to build an array using range (0..x) while excluding certain
>   ranges and values.

As per ruby-docs, you can excluded *a* range using [`Enumerable#grep_v`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v):

```
(1..10).grep_v(2..4) #=> [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

`grep_v` only defines one parameter so to exclude more than one range you would have to do something like:

```
(1..10).grep_v(2..4).grep_v(6..8) #=> [1, 5, 9, 10]
```

Values can be used as the argument if a range is not required e.g. `grep_v(1)`.